Prompting ChatGPT to restructure a given text
I want to prompt ChatGPT to restructure a given text according to a provided schema. The issue is that I can not seem to bring it to restructure everything that is contained in the document. It always summarizes sentences and leaves out most of the actual text. The goal is clear: ChatGPT should rearrange every sentence of a given text and order it based on a given schema. I don't want it to summarize anything. I don't want any sentence of the text to be left out. Is there a good prompt to prevent it from synthesizing any text / leaving it out / summarizing / rephrasing and just rearrange the data?


Is there a good prompt to prevent it from synthesizing any text / leaving it out / summarizing / rephrasing and just rearrange the data?


State so explicitly in the prompt.
Add examples in the prompt.


"You are expected to sort every sentence provided in the documents with respect to the given schema. Therefore your answer has to contain every sentence that is contained in the original document."
"You are not allowed to use your own words / you are only allowed to use the exact sentences provided in the document. Furthermore, since you have to use every sentence from the original document your answer should be at least as long as the original document."

These are the prompts im using that at least after some iterations seem to bring it to finally reuse at least most parts of the documents. However even then it leaves out sentences and starts to summarize some parts. Is there something im missing? I try to be as explicit as possible here but still it struggles to follow the instructions.
